Azure AI Search split PDF by page and retrieve page number
I'm actually working in a project where I have a Sharepoint with a bunch of PDF files stored in it. I need to store these files in Azure AI Search to perform semantic search.
When I perform retrieval over my Index, I need to recover not only the relevant information but also in which page this information is stored. The Azure AI Search SplitSkill says that it can split documents by pages, but it actually splits them by chunks and I cannot retrieve the page number from there.
So for this, I created a simple Custom Skill that gets the PDF binary, split it by pages using PyMuPDF and put it into an Azure Function, so I can create a WebApiSkill to split the PDF into pages and retrieve both, the page content (to be later further chunked and embedded) and the page number.
The code for the split is simple:
import fitz
import json

def split_pdf_by_pages(pdf_bytes):
    pdf_document = fitz.open(stream=pdf_bytes, filetype="pdf")
    pages = []
    
    for page_num in range(len(pdf_document)):
        page = pdf_document.load_page(page_num)
        text = page.get_text("text")
        pages.append({
            "page_number": page_num + 1,
            "content": text
        })
    
    return json.dumps(pages)

I still can't solve this problem, because seems that when I read information from Sharepoint, the objects that reach to my CustomSkill are no binaries, so my code fails.
Do anyone knows how to solve this? Any other way to actually split the PDFs in the Sharepoint by actual pages and retrieve the page number?

Your question might get better views if you add a tag for the coding language you're using.

@devlincarnate you're right, thanks you very much. Updated!

Use the Microsoft Graph API to fetch the file's binary content from SharePoint.
Here is the way to retrieve the binary content of a PDF from SharePoint using Microsoft Graph.
import requests

def get_file_content_from_sharepoint(site_id, drive_id, item_id, access_token):
    url = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site_id}/drives/{drive_id}/items/{item_id}/content"
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}'
    }
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.content  # Binary content of the PDF
    else:
        raise Exception(f"Error retrieving file: {response.status_code}, {response.text}")


Sometimes, binary data may be passed as a base64-encoded string. If your custom skill receives the PDF as a base64-encoded string, you can decode it before processing with PyMuPDF.

app.py:
import fitz
import base64
import json

def split_pdf_by_pages(pdf_base64):
    # Decode the base64-encoded PDF
    pdf_bytes = base64.b64decode(pdf_base64)
    
    # Open the PDF document using PyMuPDF
    pdf_document = fitz.open(stream=pdf_bytes, filetype="pdf")
    pages = []
    
    # Loop through pages and extract text and page number
    for page_num in range(len(pdf_document)):
        page = pdf_document.load_page(page_num)
        text = page.get_text("text")
        pages.append({
            "page_number": page_num + 1,
            "content": text
        })
    
    return json.dumps(pages)

The input field contains the base64-encoded PDF or the raw binary content.
Decoding Base64-Encoded PDF Data:
[INFO] 2024-10-01 10:47:00 - Azure Function triggered. Processing incoming request.
[DEBUG] 2024-10-01 10:47:01 - Received base64-encoded PDF data. Decoding...
[INFO] 2024-10-01 10:47:02 - Successfully decoded base64 data. File size: 1.2 MB
[DEBUG] 2024-10-01 10:47:03 - Splitting PDF file into pages...
[INFO] 2024-10-01 10:47:04 - Split complete. Total pages: 10

[INFO] 2024-10-01 10:47:00 - Azure Function triggered. Processing incoming request.
[DEBUG] 2024-10-01 10:47:01 - Received base64-encoded PDF data. Decoding...
[ERROR] 2024-10-01 10:47:02 - Failed to decode base64-encoded PDF data. Invalid input or corrupted base64 string.

[INFO] 2024-10-01 10:48:00 - Successfully opened PDF file. Total pages: 10
[DEBUG] 2024-10-01 10:48:01 - Processing page 1...
[DEBUG] 2024-10-01 10:48:01 - Extracted content from page 1: "**Lorem Ipsum** is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry."
[DEBUG] 2024-10-01 10:48:02 - Processing page 2...
[DEBUG] 2024-10-01 10:48:02 - Extracted content from page 2: "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout."
[INFO] 2024-10-01 10:48:10 - PDF split complete. Total pages processed: 10

[INFO] 2024-10-01 10:48:00 - Successfully opened PDF file. Total pages: 10
[DEBUG] 2024-10-01 10:48:01 - Processing page 1...
[ERROR] 2024-10-01 10:48:02 - Failed to extract content from page 1. Error: "Invalid file format or corrupt page."

[INFO] 2024-10-01 10:49:00 - Preparing to send processed data to Azure Cognitive Search.
[DEBUG] 2024-10-01 10:49:01 - Sending the following data to Azure Search:
        {
            "values": [
                {"page_number": 1, "content": "**Lorem Ipsum** is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry."},
                {"page_number": 2, "content": "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout."}
            ]
        }
[INFO] 2024-10-01 10:49:02 - Data sent successfully to Azure Search.


